# How to update a PostgreSQL table with a count of duplicate items

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, duplicates

I found two bugs in a program that created a lot of duplicate values:

- an 'index' was created instead of a 'unique index'
- a duplication checks wasn't integrated in one of 4 twisted routines

So I need to go in and clean up my database.

Step one is to decorate the table with a count of all the duplicate values (next I'll look into finding the first value, and then migrating everything over )

The code below works, I just recall doing a similar "update from select count" on the same table years ago, and I did it in half as much code.

Is there a better way to write this?

```
UPDATE 
    shared_link 
SET 
    is_duplicate_of_count = subquery.is_duplicate_of_count 
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            count(url) AS is_duplicate_of_count 
            , url
        FROM 
            shared_link
        WHERE
            shared_link.url = url
        GROUP BY 
            url
    ) AS subquery
WHERE 
    shared_link.url = subquery.url
;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You query is fine, generally, except for the pointless (but also harmless) WHERE clause in the subquery:

```
UPDATE shared_link 
SET    is_duplicate_of_count = subquery.is_duplicate_of_count 
FROM  (
    SELECT url
         , count(url) AS is_duplicate_of_count 
    FROM   shared_link
--  WHERE  shared_link.url = url
    GROUP  BY url
    ) AS subquery
WHERE shared_link.url = subquery.url;
```

The commented clause is the same as

```
WHERE  shared_link.url = shared_link.url
```

and therefore only eliminating `NULL` values (because `NULL = NULL` is not `TRUE`), which is most probably neither intended nor needed in your setup.

---

Other than that you can only shorten your code further with aliases and shorter names:

```
UPDATE shared_link s
SET    ct = u.ct
FROM  (
    SELECT url, count(url) AS ct
    FROM   shared_link
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) AS u
WHERE s.url = u.url;
```

In PostgreSQL 9.1 or later you might be able to do the *whole operation* (identify dupes, consolidate data, remove dupes) in *one* SQL statement with aggregate and window functions and [**data-modifying CTEs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) - thereby eliminating the need for an additional column to begin with.

Comment: Thanks so much, Erwin!  I'm still on the 8.4.x branch on this machine.